# ResultSet only showing 1 row when there are actually many rows

Tags: java, swing

**I'm doing a project for my college. I'm using resultSet to select all the rows from a newspaper table and I'm adding each newspaper name to a JComboBox. I  have many newspapers added but the resultSet selects only the first row.**

```
    try{
        combobox1.removeAllItems();
        ResultSet r1= MysqlCon.run("select * from "+pub);
        while(r1.next())
        {
            combobox1.addItem(r1.getString("name"));
            System.out.println(r1.getString(2));
        }
        //TODO
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
```

Here is the class which takes connection to the database

```
 import java.sql.*;  
class MysqlCon{  
    static ResultSet rs;
    public static ResultSet run(String query)
    {
        try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","gijo","root");  
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(query); 

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);} 
        return rs;
    }
```

I'm using the same class to add values to a JTable and there is no problem there.

**Please help me!**

Comment: ***NEVER*** ignore exceptions. Since you `select * `, how do you know that column "2" returns `String`?

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong, totally wrong, to return a ResultSet from a function and lost the reference of the `Statement` and `Connection`.

GC might come across these objects and consider mark them not in use and run their `finalize` method. As a result the connection may have dropped at random point in time.

You might rewrite your API, or you can study about `CachedResultSet` form Oracle.

Comment: So what do i do now?
I have many classes in my project and i don't wish to create Connections in every class. Theres a similar part in my program where i use the same technique to create a JTable and it seems to work fine.
Only this combobox part !